# Getting values from an api ordered by a common parameter

Tags: php, json, api

How would one go about listing all the values in this api in a html table ordered by their "position24" value?

I know how to call each individual value, but I'm not sure of how to automatically load them in that order.

http://www.coincap.io/front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your API, decode the JSON, sort it by this key and return it in a table. The following lines are a base for your solution.

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    return intval($a->position24) - intval($b->position24);
}

$json = file_get_contents('http://www.coincap.io/front');
$data = json_decode($json);
usort($data, 'compare');
// display $data in a table
```

If you use classes and the compare function (`compare`) is in the same class as the usort-function-call you should use:

```
usort($data, array($this, 'compare'));
```

**UPDATE:**

You can echo out your table by calling the attribute like this:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row->long;
    echo $row->position24;
}
```

Because there are so many values, I let it up to, which one you want to display. If you need help how to build a table you find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not getting any values to show though. Could you point me to a resource where I can learn how to tie this to the other values?